# Where is redis.conf in phpredis

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

I am new to phpredis and am confused where the redis.conf file is for nicolasff's repository. It is not in the configure file. When I installed redis through the tar.gz there was a file called redis.conf which was helpful.

Do I need to remake redis after I alter the configuration file?

This is the github link to the repository.
https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis

Comment: Isn't phpredis a client? redis.conf is for the server not the client.

Comment: Wow I think you made me realize I misread the documentation I guess. I can't confirm this yet until I set up the instance.